# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

First of all, this error started happening about two weeks ago and I honestly don't think I have changed any configuration.

I have an ASP.NET application that targets framework 4.7.2. It was working fine until two weeks ago. But now when I use the "Local IIS" debug function and then stop debugging, two things happen:

1. When trying to run debug again, I get the following error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The remote server
>   returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

2. Before and during the first debug round, I can access the website via a browser. But after I stop debugging, I get 404-Not found when trying to access the site via its url. Detailed information includes: "Handler: StaticFile".

I can access the site as soon as I exit Visual Studio. And I can debug fine when I reopen the Visual Studio IDE.

**Note1:** I am using Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.15

**Note2:** IIS reset does not help. Only restarting Visual Studio helps.

Answer (score 0):

[From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2019#server_error):

There are many possible causes for this error, so check your log file and the IIS security settings for the web site.

Make sure the server's web.config includes `debug=true` in the compilation element.

Make sure that your Web Application folder has the right permissions and that your Application Pool configuration is correct (a password may have changed). 
See Check your [IIS Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2019#vxtbshttpservererrorsthingstocheck).

If these settings are already correct and you are debugging locally, also verify that you are connecting to the correct server type and URL (in Properties > Web > Servers or Properties > Debug, depending on your project type).